# Is subclassing QTextEdit for keyPressEvent override the only way?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, textview, pyside2

I'm building a Qt application with PySide2 which will have at least one texteditor-like view. I have two reasons for wanting to modify the functionality of QTextEdit's `keyPressEvent` method:

1. To add the ability to have user-defined keyboard actions to manipulate the text (such as the standard indent/dedent using tab/shift+tab, although there will many others).
2. To facilitate some future features, the text being displayed will be stored in a substantially different structure (not HTML/RTF/etc., but a tree). This leads me to believe that I can't use the QTextEdit as a combined View+Controller, but will have to extract the Controller logic to correctly modify the underlying structure after each key press, and feed the generated text to QTextEdit. (Although, I have thought about making use of the fact that QTextEdit uses HTML under the hood, to possibly hide the structure using `div` or `a` tags. **note below**)

Given that Python is interpreted, the combination of these two -plus the desire to also use QSyntaxHighlighter- concerns me. If there is a ton of business logic executed on each keypress, it stands to reason it could eventually be very noticeable. Now, I don't want to prematurely optimize, but I would like to avoid heading down a path where it seems likely I'll have to make a more time-consuming change. I'm just curious if, short of writing the QTextEdit subclass in C++, if there is some other method I haven't thought of that would likely be more performant.

Or, if a C++ subclass of QTextEdit seems required, if overriding `keyPressEvent` is the best method.

**note the following update is not directly related to the desire to inject business login into QTextEdit's input handling (and dividing the view/controller responsibilities), but is to provide information to anyone else that has a similar use-case as item 2:** Just played around with the widget in QtDesigner, and neither an `<a>` anchor nor a `<meta>` tag will work to at least "tag" the structure elements, while also being non-visible to the user. (`<a name="something"></a>` doesn't move with the text, and `<meta>` is always moved into the head).

Comment: mmm, your last edition has nothing to do with what you point out in the previous part. To me it smells like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what is your specific objective?. Or worse, your question is too broad, don't ask too much in one question.

Comment: I don't think it is too much. I'm asking if my proposal to inject code into the input handling process is a less-than-optimal solution. And I provided larger context as to why I wanted to do this. However, I will clarify.

Comment: I point it out because fferri's answer meets "1" and you should be able to extend it to "2" but it's clearly complicated. I think it would be better if you create a new question for "2" bypassing the prerequisite of keyPressEvent, something like: "I want X, Y and Z, for example if I write" W "must happen" w ", etc. So far I tried using keyPressEvent: show code, etc ". That would be more extensible. Since from the title "you force" to think that the solution is keyPressEvent and perhaps there is another alternative, for example the answer of fferri can be replaced using QShortcuts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an event filter to handle keypresses without subclassing `QTextEdit`.

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.edit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        self.edit.installEventFilter(self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)

    def eventFilter(self, widget, event):
        if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress and
            widget is self.edit):
            key = event.key()
            if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
                print('escape')
            else:
                if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
                    self.edit.setText('return')
                elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter:
                    self.edit.setText('enter')
                return True
        return QtGui.QWidget.eventFilter(self, widget, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 300, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: (just tested it) Yes, that does remove the need to subclass (for case 1). However, the same issue could arise, since all of the logic is handled in Python.

Comment: That sounds like premature optimization. But in general, you could take any CPU-intensive algorithm and port it to C/C++ and make it into a Python extension, thus maintaining most of your application logic in Python/Qt.